# How do you collapse a category in PropertyPanel in Forge Viewer v7?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the Forge Viewer to display properties on selected items in my model.

When an object is selected, I want to automatically show the properties panel but keep a category collapsed. Here's the code I'm using in an attempt to achieve this:

```js
        viewer.addEventListener(
          Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, 
          () => {
            const panel = viewer.getPropertyPanel();
            panel.setVisible(true);
            panel.setCategoryCollapsed("Category Name", true);
          },  
        );
```

The event is raised and the panel is shown, however, the function `setCategoryCollapsed` does not work (understandable as it was last [documented in v5](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/propertypanel/#setcategorycollapsed-category-collapsed)). Is there a similar function in v7 to collapse a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function expects an object with **name** and **type** properties - e.g. if I wanted to collapse the "Graphics" category, I could do it like this:

```
const panel = viewer.getPropertyPanel();
panel.setVisible(true);
panel.setCategoryCollapsed({name: "Graphics", type: "category"}, true);
```

Have also just written a blog post about it now: [Collapse category in the Property Panel](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/collapse-category-property-panel)